# Impossible? Would like to dynamically change an iframe source on my domain from an email

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

To make it so when a client clicks an email link to send them to a webpage & change the src of my iframe within that webpage.

To make the problem even more challenging, this email link is dynamically generated by the software and thus unique.

Below is the auto generated html code(link) from the program I'm using. "event contract".

Tried "Target" for iframes but they only seem to work within the same page.

```html
<a href="https://myoffice.co/include/email/click.php?id=24793587&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fmyoffice.co%2Fquotes%2Fcontractme.php%3Fname%3DNancy%2BBoy%2BNew%2BCustomer%26qid%3D4353885%26cid%3D3832239" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://myoffice.co/include/email/click.php?id%3D247923587%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmyoffice.co%252Fquotes%252Fcontractme.php%253Fname%253DNancy%252Bboy%252BNew%252BCustomer%2526qid%253D43532285%2526cid%253D38212239&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1548289338892000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFhqWaB3GBJOGNf5qqwUJhVL5naeA">Event Contract</a>
```

Comment: Show your JS code.

Comment: Change soure of iframe to what? the url that is in the url ? Why not just put it as src='yoururl'. If the page you are trying to access have restrictive policies it will not work.

Comment: The URL is dynamic.  The program generates a contract with a unique URL.

Comment: JS was not deployed in this, I don't even know where to begin!

Comment: The program we are using generates a unique URL for each contract it sends over email.  It would be nice if we could remove their "branding" by pointing the contract to an iframe on our domain instead of the link taking you to their domain.